# Clone &[u32] to [u32]

Tags: rust, clone

I'm doing some coding practice and the problem is defining a function with parameters as &[u32]. I wanna do some alter with it so the best way is to copy it into a mutable variable so that I can freely alter. I try using let v = a.clone() but it keeps giving me a &[u32] rather than an [u32], I know it obviously gives &[u32] but I really don't know how to convert it to [u32]. I try looking it up but couldn't find anything!
Please help! Thank you so much!

Comment: Your best bet would be to make a `Vec<u32>` via [`a.to_vec()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.to_vec) or [`a.to_owned()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#impl-ToOwned). Getting a `[u32]` isn't very useful because its an unsized type and can't really be used without indirection via `&` or `Box<_>`.

Comment: How is this question unclear? The OP describes the use case (wanting to mutate a clone of a slice), as well as attempts to resolve the issue (calling `clone()` on the slice).

Answer (score 4):

A `&[u32]` is represented by a (pointer, length) pair, where the pointer points to the array of integers, and the length records how many of them there are. A `[u32]`, on the other hand, doesn't contain a pointer, it literally means "some amount of `u32` here". Rust calls such types [unsized](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.2.0/book/unsized-types.html) and you are very limited with what you can do with them - they typically must be referenced indirectly. So if you want to copy the slice in order to mutate it, you will need to create a (pointer, length) pair of your own.

As you discovered, calling `clone()` on a `&[u32]` doesn't accomplish anything because it clones the shared *reference*, i.e. gives you another instance of a pointer/length pair pointing to the same data. What you want is an actual copy.

Generally making a copy of `&[u32]` can't result in a new `&[u32]` because `&` is a reference to data owned by someone else. Since you need to create a fresh copy of the data, you will need someone to own it. This is what a `Box` is used for, so what you want is a `Box<[u32]>`, which has the exact same stack representation as `&[u32]`, a (pointer, length) pair. The easiest way to copy a `&[T]` into a new `Box<T>` is using the [`to_vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.to_vec) method to create a temporary `Vec<T>`. A `Vec<T>` is like `Box<[T]>`, except it also tracks the capacity of the memory (how much data was allocated), which allows efficient adding of new elements. Since you won't add new elements, you can immediately convert the vector into a box:

```rust
fn mutate(x: &[u32]) {
    // copy x into Box<[u32]> through a temporary Vec
    let mut copy: Box<[u32]> = x.to_vec().into_boxed_slice();

    // now that we own the copy, we can create &mut [u32] into it
    let mref: &mut [u32] = copy.as_mut();
    mref[0] = 10;  // ...

    // at the end of scope, the slice we own is deallocated
}
```

Turning `Vec<T>` into `Box<T>` is efficient because the storage used by `Vec` is reused for the `Box`. The difference is just that the "capacity" counter used by `Vec` is discarded, so the resuting value is again represented on the stack by a (pointer, length) pair instead of a (pointer, length, capacity) triple.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, thank you so much. This is so helpful. I’m supposed to finish reading the book before doing thing but I am too impatient, seems like I must finish it. Anyway, I’m very grateful!

Comment: @HuyPhan You're welcome! And if the question is resolved, feel free to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/627709).